# Attempting to push a UIViewController onto a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm currently working on an app that retrieves a list of films from the rotten tomatoes API and displays them in a table. I'd like a UIViewController to show up once I tap on a row so I can display a detailed page.

Here's the code I have for my didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    //UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self]; // This line of code throws an exception for some reason. 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

It might be that I haven't slept for a very long time but I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong.

PS. I'm using arc.

Comment: Are you sure your navigation controller is initialized?

Comment: Check whether the navigationController is nil by NSLog

Comment: @RehatKathuria, Just check whether it is nil or not first and then tell us what you have found

Comment: Ah, sorry. As it turns out, navigationController is nil. Where shall I init it?

Comment: see my answer below. You will most likely need to write it in your AppDelegate

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your navigation controller is initialized?

If not your are properly missing something like this in the place where you construct your `UIViewController`:

```
MyVc = [[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVc];
[_window addSubview:navCon.view];
```

Comment: I've initiated the navigation controller and a navigation bar has shown up but the NSLog tells me that it is nil. I'm confused.

Comment: sounds strange. perhaps you are still adding your old view to the  _window?. You should only add a single view to the _window, namely the view from the navCon.

Answer (score 0):

Write these properties in AppDelegate.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourFirstViewController *yourFirstController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationControl;
```

Write this code in AppDelegate.m file

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        self.yourFirstViewController = [[YourFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourFirstViewController" bundle:nil]];
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.yourFirstViewController];
        [self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.